# IPython.parallel.Client() not working

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

There is no problem when I import IPython.parallel -->`import IPython.parallel` 
However, when I try this: 
`rc=IPython.parallel.Client()` 
I get the following error:

```
/home/mycomputer/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/shimmodule.pyc in __getattr__(self, key)
     90             return import_item(name)
     91         except ImportError:
---> 92             raise AttributeError(key)

AttributeError: Client
```

Does anyone know the solution to this?
[I am using Ubuntu 14.04]

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with IPython 4.0's shim. `IPython.parallel` has moved to a new package, `ipyparallel`, so if you are using 4.0:

```
import ipyparallel
rc = ipyparallel.Client()
```

It's possible that the failure is that you don't have `ipyparallel`, and you are getting an unfortunately uninformative failure instead of a nice, useful error message. In that case:

```
pip install --upgrade ipyparallel
```

(or `conda install`, depending on your Python packaging of choice).